# How can I use Stanford NLP commercially?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm working on the company that makes toy cars that can talk with children. We want to use Stanford Core NLP as a parser. However, it is licensed in GPL: they doesn't allow using the NLP commercially. Can I purchase other license from Stanford NLP group? Or can't I use the NLP commercially?

This might not be appropriate as a public question, but I can't find direct contact to Stanford NLP group.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You *can* use GPL software commercially. You just can't hide its source (your code needs to be GPL too). For example, it is perfectly legal to sell GNU/Linux DVDs, as long as all the source code is available and the GPL is preserved in your distribution. Whether this makes sense for your business model or not is your decision, of course. (Also, direct contact via mailing lists [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml#Mail), although they indicate they also follow `stanford-nlp` tag).

Comment: @Amadan Thank you. I'm going to send an email to the mailing list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use the  software under the GPL license, or you can purchase a commercial license. For the latter, you can contact us at the support email address found [here](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/#license).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm going to send an email to that contact.